# How to show when loan was paid off

Tags: sql-server-2005, cursors, business-intelligence, dml

First time posting but have been a reader for over 10 years. I have a need to show when a loan was paid off regardless of the rolling balance from refinancing/taking out additional loans.

In the other column I want to show pay down balance like
950.00, 850.00, 800.00, 720.00 until I get to zero balance for the LOAN_ID 215, After which I want  to then apply remaining payments to LOAN_ID 431

I'm using SQL Server 2005/2008.

Here is my table:

```
CUST_ID LOAN_ID PMNT_ID PMNT_AMT  PMNT_DT   LOAN_AMT  LOAN_FUND_DT  PMNT_RUN_TOT  
1155      215    100    100.00   02/15/2015  1050.00   01/15/2015    100.00
1155      215    101    100.00   03/15/2015  1050.00   01/15/2015    200.00
1155      215    102     50.00   03/31/2015  1050.00   01/15/2015    250.00
1155      215    103     90.00   04/15/2015  1050.00   01/15/2015    340.00
1155      215    104    150.00   04/25/2015  1050.00   01/15/2015    490.00
1155      215    105    120.00   05/15/2015  1050.00   01/15/2015    610.00
1155      431    106    100.00   05/25/2015  2100.00   05/20/2015    710.00
1155      431    107    100.00   06/15/2015  2100.00   05/20/2015    810.00
1155      431    108    100.00   06/30/2015  2100.00   05/20/2015    910.00
1155      431    109    100.00   07/15/2015  2100.00   05/20/2015    1010.00
1155      431    110    100.00   08/15/2015  2100.00   05/20/2015    1110.00
1155      431    111    100.00   09/15/2015  2100.00   05/20/2015    1210.00
1155      431    112    100.00   09/30/2015  2100.00   05/20/2015    1310.00
1155      431    113    100.00   10/15/2015  2100.00   05/20/2015    1410.00
```

The first loan was paid off with `PMNT_ID 110` and 60.00 was rolled over into the pay down of 2100.00 loan. Here is how the output should look

### cust_id|loan_id | loan_amount | Loan Bal  |paid_off_date

1155 |     215|        1050 |    0.00    |2015-08-15
  1155 |     431|        2100 | 1800.00    |null

Any suggestions on how to show this in another column called "Bal_Pay_Down" ?

Comment: I would add another field and label it LOAN_PNMT_ID, use the loan_id that the pmt_amt is being applied to, instead of the loan_id of the loan. Then it'd be pretty easy to calculate a running total, use the loan_pmt_id and pmnt_amt to get your running balances.

Comment: In the other column I want to show pay down bal like
950.00, 850.00, 800.00, 720.00 until I get to 0 for the LOAN_ID 215, After which I want  to then apply remaining payments to LOAN_ID 431

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, I did the following (+1 for the question BTW - it was an interesting challenge and I learnt a lot by going through it).

The code below can be found on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=ec05d5fad34cb01b05f7a02afd8ca923) (Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Linux - works on all versions on dbfiddle going back to 2014) :

Created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE payment (CUST_ID int, LOAN_ID int, PMNT_ID int, PMNT_AMT float,  PMNT_DT date,   LOAN_AMT float,  LOAN_FUND_DT date,  PMNT_RUN_TOT int);
```

Populated the table:

```
INSERT INTO payment VALUES (1155,      215,         100,         100.00,   '2015-02-15',           300.00,        '2015-01-15' ,       100.00);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES (1155,      215,         101,          50.00,   '2015-03-15',           300.00,        '2015-01-15' ,       150.00);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES (1155,      215,         102,          75.00,   '2015-04-15',           300.00,        '2015-01-15' ,       225.00);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES (1155,      215,         103,          75.00,   '2015-05-15',           300.00,        '2015-01-15' ,       300.00);

INSERT INTO payment VALUES (1156,      223,         104,          30.00,   '2015-02-15',           390.00,        '2015-01-15' ,        30.00);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES (1156,      223,         105,          30.00,   '2015-03-15',           390.00,        '2015-01-15' ,        60.00);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES (1156,      223,         106,         300.00,   '2015-04-15',           390.00,        '2015-01-15' ,       360.00);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES (1156,      223,         107,          30.00,   '2015-07-27',           390.00,        '2015-01-15' ,       390.00);
```

And then I ran the following query (don't worry about the overkill/repetition on the `PARTITION BY`s - I was trying to get to grips with Window functions).

```
WITH tab1 AS
(
  SELECT n.cust_id, n.loan_id, n.pmnt_id, pmnt_dt, pmnt_amt,
  SUM(n.pmnt_amt) OVER (PARTITION BY n.cust_id, n.loan_id) AS loans,
  SUM(n.pmnt_amt) OVER (PARTITION BY n.pmnt_id) AS payments,
  SUM(n.pmnt_amt) OVER () AS grand_total,
  SUM(n.pmnt_amt) OVER (partition by loan_id ORDER BY pmnt_id) AS payment_per_loan,
  SUM(n.pmnt_amt) OVER (ORDER BY loan_id) AS loans_cumulative,
  SUM(n.pmnt_amt) OVER (PARTITION BY n.loan_id) loan_amount,
  (SUM(n.pmnt_amt) OVER (PARTITION BY n.cust_id, n.loan_id)) - 
  (SUM(n.pmnt_amt) OVER (partition by loan_id ORDER BY pmnt_id)) AS remainder_per_loan
  FROM payment AS n
  ORDER BY cust_id, n.loan_id, n.pmnt_id, n.pmnt_dt
)
SELECT cust_id, loan_id, loan_amount, pmnt_dt AS paid_off_date FROM tab1
WHERE remainder_per_loan = 0
```

And the result is (with the limited subset of data that I used):

```
cust_id|loan_id|loan_amount|paid_off_date
----------------------------------------------------
  1155|     215|        300|     2015-05-15
  1156|     223|        390|     2015-07-27
```

Comment: Wont work the scope of my question was changed.. A loan is not paid off before another is taken.

Comment: Yea you are correct :)

Comment: It seems helpful but I am using SQL 2005 and it seems the order by part is not recognized. SMH.

Comment: Let me try it again in SQL Server because it works in oracle perfectly

Comment: Not working in 2005

Comment: I don't mean to be smart, but you could upgrade. SQL Server has had 4-5 editions since 2005 - it's over 10 years old. If you don't want to fork out cash, then use PostgreSQL? That's what I wrote my query on. Maybe there's a way to do it using variables like in MySQL, but I'm not familiar enough with T-SQL to help.  I can only suggest that debugging tricky workarounds could also cost money.

Comment: Yes I agree will you on the upgrade part.

Comment: THANKS! I appreciate your effort ... It did not work but I learned a few things.